# How to make Drupal 6 search result URL have ".html" at the end?

Tags: 6, search, uri

I want the search result URL become

```
http://www.site.com/search/node/Search for something.html
http://www.site.com/search/node/cars.html
```

I've looked into `custom_url_rewrite_outbound()` but there is not much I can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[custom_url_rewrite_outbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_outbound/6) is not the only function you need to place in settings.php; you need also [custom_url_rewrite_inbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6), which converts back the URL to the one known by Drupal.

For those functions, you can use code similar to the following one:

```
function custom_url_rewrite_outbound(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  if (preg_match('|^search/([^/]+)/(.+)|', $path, $matches)) {
    $path = 'search/' . $matches[1] . '/' . $matches[2] . '.html';
  }
}

function custom_url_rewrite_inbound(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
  if (preg_match('|^search/([^/]+)/(.+)\.html$|', $path, $matches)) {
    $result = 'search/' . $matches[1] . '/' . $matches[2];
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, instead of custom_url_rewrite_inbound I would rather use a mod_rewrite rule.